# Is "if I were president of this country, I would have made everyone in this country rich" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, conditional-constructions

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> If I were president of this country, I would have made everyone in this country rich.

What I mean is "if (something happened in the past) then (effect of that event in the present)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, OP's example isn't "correct", because the verb forms are inconsistent. The consistent versions are...

> 1: *"If I **were** president of this country, I **would make** everyone in this country rich"*
>    2: *"If I **had been** president of this country, I **would have made** everyone in this country rich"*

In #1 the speaker is postulating an "unreal" situation in which he ***is*** president *at the time of speaking*, but in #2 it's when he ***was*** president (also unreal, since he never was, but crucially, it's *in the past*).

Note that technically speaking, #1 is a "true" subjunctive usage. The equivalent past tense version for #2 would be *"If I **would have been** president"*, but almost nobody ever says that, because we increasingly tend to avoid the subjunctive. People still commonly say things like *"If **I'd have been** president"*, but in my experience if you ask what that **'d** stands for they'll often say it's a shortening of *if I **had have been*** (which is grammatically nonsense, but it just goes to show we *don't like the subjunctive*).

Answer (score 0):

To express what you want to say, you should say:

> If I had been president of this country, I would have made everyone in this country rich.

This sentence is similar to the following one (See [How to ask the question in conditional sentences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8591/how-to-ask-the-question-in-conditional-sentences))

> Would Chinese people have loved tradition if China had not been a communist country?

"If I were president in this country" introduces an [irrealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis), something that will never happen; in that case, you should write "I would make everyone in this country rich."
It is similar to the following sentence.

> If I were rich, I would live on Long Island. *I am not rich, and I will never be rich; therefore, I will never live on Long Island.*

This is different from the following sentence.

> If I take the 6:00 PM train, I will arrive in time. *There is a chance I can take the 6:00 PM train; therefore, there is a chance I will arrive in time.*

Comment: thnakyou for that .. i will keep that in mind :P

Answer (score -2):

If you say, "If I had been the President", than you must have been the president at some point of time in the past.

Comment: Completely wrong.  It doesn't mean that at all.

Comment: Aw! Would you mind reading something called subjunctive mood?